# ABE and OKAMOTO definition of partially blind signature scheme

Tags: signature, blind-signature

I'm trying to understand the definition of a partially blind scheme that is described with Game A presented in

[Abe and Okamoto paper](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2000/18800272/18800272.pdf)

[image: Game A part 1]

[image: Game A prt 2]

1. In line 5 is $msg_0$ correct or should it be replaced by $(info_0,msg_b,sig_b)$? similarly for $U_1$. I'm confused since  if $msg_0$ is always on the private tape of $U_0$ then S can always guess b correctly by checking if $sig_b$ verifies $msg_0$.

I'm missing the point here I'm certain.
Thank you for helping out.